# Как сделать так, чтоб при наведении на ссылку подсвечивались все ссылки этого класса?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ссылки

Есть две ссылки. Как сделать так, чтоб при наведении на любую из них подсвечивались обе? В один контейнер их поместить нельзя, они разбросаны по странице.

UPD: Вот как это выглядит.

HTML:

```
<a href="/" class="eye1">Глаз 1</a>
<a href="/" class="eye2">Глаз 2</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {opacity: 0;}
a:hover {opacity: 1 !important;} 
.eye1:hover ~ .eye2 {opacity: 1 !important;}
```

При наведении курсора на .eye1 появляется .eye2, но не наоборот. А надо, чтоб работало в две стороны.

Comment: дайте больше данных. в противном случае, что вам мешает прописать для выбранных классов `:hover`? Если имеет место динамическое добавление ссылок с генерируемыми классами - это другой вопрос. Минимальный пример не помешает.

Comment: Так ведь если прописывать `:hover`, при наведении будет подсвечиваться только ссылка, на которую навели.

Comment: Отредактировал, добавил пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой простенький скрипт без использования библиотек.

Класс подсветки `highlight` настраивается в стилях.

Соединяются все элементы с заданным классом, в данном случае `class1`.

```js
ColorBind("class1");

function ColorBind(className) {

  var ells = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

  var highlightToggle = function() {
    var all = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

    for (var el1 of all) {
      el1.classList.toggle("highlight");
    }
  }

  for (var el of ells) {
    el.addEventListener("mouseover", highlightToggle);
    el.addEventListener("mouseout", highlightToggle);
  }
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="class1">Человек</a>
<a href="#" class="class1">Лось</a>
<a href="#" class="class2">Тигр</a>
<p>
  Дружно могут жить
</p>
<a href="#" class="class1">Собака</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

при наведении на ссылку выполнять поиск всех ссылок и уже выполнять с ними действия, если я, правильно понял

Comment: Правильно. Но как это реализовать на JS? Я, если что, полный ноль. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

могу предложить для примера jQuery

```
$('a').hover(function () {
    $('a').css({"color": "red"});
},function () {
    $('a').css({"color": "black"});
});
```